# Pulumi: Delete a ConfigMap after Job execution by code

Tags: kubernetes, pulumi

I created a ConfigMap with Pulumi:

```
    // Create setup script
    const argoCDInitialSetupScript = new k8s.core.v1.ConfigMap('argo-cd-setup', {
      metadata: {
        name: 'argo-cd-setup',
        namespace: 'argo',
      },
      data: {
        'init-argo.sh': fs.readFileSync("src/assets/yaml/argo-cd/argo-cd-setup.sh").toString()
      },
    });
```

Next, I run a Job that will use this ConfigMap and when the Job completes, I want to delete this ConfigMap but I cannot find how to do so in Pulumi!

I would have expected something like this:

```
    // Delete Config Map
    argoCDInitialSetupScript.delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

With Pulumi once the job is done, you can simply run the command to destroy.

```
$ pulumi destroy
```

Refer to [link](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/kubernetes/how-to-guides/configmap-rollout/) for more information.